# Twitter4j authentication credentials are missing

Tags: java, android, api, twitter, twitter4j

I would like to make a tweet with Twitter4j in my Android app. Here is my code:

```
 //TWITTER SHARE.
@Click (R.id. img_btn_twitter)
@Background
public void twitterPostWall(){

    try {


        //Twitter Conf.
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_KEY)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_SECRET);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

        try {
            RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

            Log.e("Request token: ", "" + requestToken.getToken());
            Log.e("Request token secret: ", "" + requestToken.getTokenSecret());
            AccessToken accessToken = null;


        }

        catch (IllegalStateException ie) {

            if (!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()) {
                Log.e("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.", "");
            }
        }


        Status status = twitter.updateStatus(postLink);
        Log.e("Successfully updated the status to [", ""  + status.getText() + "].");

    }

    catch (TwitterException te) {
        Log.e("TWEET FAILED", "");

    }
}
```

I always get this error message from Twitter4j: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for the detail. But as you can see I'm using builder to set my key. Can someone help me to fix it please? thanks.

Comment: You never use the TwitterFactory instance 'tf' ...

Comment: Yes but I don't think it's the point of this problem.

Comment: Well, it kinda is, because you say 'as you can see I'm using builder to set my key', but then the only object to use the builder is 'tf', which is never used. Therefore, setting the credentials on builder has zero effect.
You need to create the 'twitter' object with: `Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();`
And drop the call to  `twitter.setOAuthConsumer`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem is following lines.

```
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
```

You are passing the configuration to one `TwitterFactory` instance and using another `TwitterFactory` instance to get the `Twitter` instance.

Hence, You are getting 
 `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing`

I suggest you to modify your code as follows:

```
    //Twitter Conf.
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_KEY)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_SECRET);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

And use this twitter instance. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the configuration on Twitter4j because I was not providing the right configuration. So in order to fix it, I created the following function to establish my configuration to later be used in another function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    TwitterServiceImpl impl = new TwitterServiceImpl();
    ResponseList<Status> resList = impl.getUserTimeLine("spacex");

    for (Status status : resList) {
        System.out.println(status.getCreatedAt() + ": " + status.getText());
    }
}

public ResponseList<Status> getUserTimeLine(String screenName) throws TwitterException {
    
    TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(getConfiguration().build());
    Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
    twitter.getAuthorization();
    Paging paging = new Paging(1, 10);
    twitter.getId();
    return twitter.getUserTimeline(screenName, paging);
}

public ConfigurationBuilder getConfiguration() {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("myConsumerKey")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("myConsumerSecret")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("myAccessToken")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("myAccessTokenSecret");
    return cb;
}
```

To get the required info, you must have a Twitter developer account, and to get the auth info of an app previously created go to: [Projects and Apps](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/projects/).

In the end, I was able to retrieve the data from a SpaceX account:

```
Tue Nov 24 20:58:13 CST 2020: Falcon 9 launches Starlink to orbit – the seventh launch and landing of this booster https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1331431972430700545
Tue Nov 24 20:29:36 CST 2020: Deployment of 60 Starlink satellites confirmed https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1331424769632215040
Tue Nov 24 20:23:17 CST 2020: Falcon 9’s first stage lands on the Of Course I Still Love You droneship! https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1331423180431396864
Tue Nov 24 20:14:20 CST 2020: Liftoff! https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1331420926450094080
Tue Nov 24 20:02:38 CST 2020: Watch Falcon 9 launch 60 Starlink satellites ? https://www.spacex.com/launches/index.html  https://twitter.com/i/broadcasts/1ypKdgVXWgRxW
Tue Nov 24 19:43:14 CST 2020: T-30 minutes until Falcon 9 launches its sixteenth Starlink mission. Webcast goes live ~15 minutes before liftoff https://www.spacex.com/launches/index.html
Tue Nov 24 18:00:59 CST 2020: RT @elonmusk: Good Starship SN8 static fire! Aiming for first 15km / ~50k ft altitude flight next week. Goals are to test 3 engine ascent,…
Mon Nov 23 15:45:38 CST 2020: Now targeting Tuesday, November 24 at 9:13 p.m. EST for Falcon 9’s launch of Starlink, when weather conditions in the recovery area should improve
Sun Nov 22 20:45:13 CST 2020: Standing down from today’s launch of Starlink. Rocket and payload are healthy; teams will use additional time to complete data reviews and are now working toward backup opportunity on Monday, November 23 at 9:34 p.m. but keeping an eye on recovery weather
Sat Nov 21 22:09:12 CST 2020: More Falcon 9 launch and landing photos ? https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1330362669837082624
```

[Where to get Auth Tokens for your app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUoY.png)