# Unable to authenticate using twitter4j

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

I've got a problem with trying to authenticate to Twitter using twitter4j. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638190/twitter4j-authentication-credentials-are-missing) out and yet it is still not working.

Here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
public class SpeedDemon {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
// Setup for Snake Charmer

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("CONSUMER_KEY")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("CONSUMER_SECRET")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("OAUTH_ACCESS")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("OAUTH_SECRET");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

// Gets timeline.
Twitter twit = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
List<Status> statuses = twit.getHomeTimeline();
System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
for (Status status : statuses) {
    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                       status.getText());
}

}

}
```

EDIT: The following error happens at compilation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:215)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1784)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getHomeTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:105)
at speeddemon.SpeedDemon.main(SpeedDemon.java:30)
C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you construct a Twitter instance twice, once with your constructed TwitterFactory and once with the Singleton (which I suspect doesn't have auth setup).

You then use the second Twitter instance (created with the unauthenticated factory) to make your queries.

Try using `twitter.getHomeTimeline()` rather than `twit.getHomeTimeline()`

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!